# array to object throwing Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to reconstruct an object from code. First I explode the calls to the object into an array, and then convert the array into an object, and then test to see if the call works.

The object created seems fine, but the test call fails.

```
$claim = new_client();
print_r($claim);
$pat = $claim->patientFirstName();
echo $pat;

function new_client()
{
$text = '
$claim->patientFirstName() 
UNWANTED STUFF. 
$claim->patientMiddleName()
UNWANTED STUFF.....
$claim->patientLastName() ';


$client = array();
$i = 1 ;
$array =  (explode("claim->",$text));

foreach ($array as &$variable) {
$variable = substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "()"));

$client[$variable] = $i;
$i++;
}
unset ($variable);
$object = new stdClass();
foreach ($client as $key => $value)
{
$object->$key = $value;
}
return $object;
}
```

Here is the result.

```
stdClass Object ( [] => 1 [patientFirstName] => 2 [patientMiddleName] => 3 
[patientLastName] => 4 ) 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method 
stdClass::patientFirstName()...
```

So any ideas as to why
    $pat = $claim->patientFirstName(); 
is failing?

Comment: there seems to be a quotes and period mismatch. PHP code within single quotes will not be evaluated

Comment: you are assigning a function to $claim variable and try to call other function using that variable (treating it as an class object.).   new_client() is a function or class object?

Comment: The result seems to be a well formed stdClass object as can been seen in the print_r when the code is run, so whilst this may be true, is it the answer?

Comment: new_client() is a function that returns a class object or so it appears.

Comment: It's property but not method. `$pat = $claim->patientFirstName;` will work

Comment: splash58 is absolutely right. But can anyone tell me why. My objective is not to change the code in the text file (which of course is longer is real working open source code and more complex) but to recreate the object it uses. The original uses a class to create the object. And then uses $claim->patientFirstName(). Is there some small change I can make so that the orginal file stays unchanged and I too can use $claim->patientFirstName()?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the element is a wrong way.

```
$claim->patientFirstName
$claim->patientMiddleName
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right in so far as it works. What would I need to change in order to be able to access it in the same way? The objective is to reconstruct the original object, not to change the code to access a different object.

Comment: Put a different way, why can't I access the object I created using $claim->patientFirstName()? What would an object that is accessible in this way look like in a print_r($object)  or would they look the same?

Comment: you are accessing it as partientFirstName is a function

Comment: Sorry to be slow though isn't that what I have done? Except the key_name is  a variable as it is looped through its values? $object->$key = $value;

Comment: You are accessing them wrongly check you have placed () after the key

Comment: I have 2,000+ lines of open source code that will go into the $text  - I cannot  change it because it will get undone when the code is updated - it is openEMR and highly respected code and it means changing 400 lines.  I need an object that can be accessed the same way as theirs  using $claim->patientFirstName().  My question is how to generate the original  object for this code without changing it, not change the code for a different object. All the answers are about changing the code not the object so far. I need to change my code to generate the object  not theirs. $text cannot be changed.